# Como consumir dois endpoints com axios e incrementar uma lista com o retorno do segundo endpoint?

Tags: vue.js

Pessoal tenho o seguinte método no meu projeto com vue.js:

```
      var lista = []
      axios.get(this.$store.state.baseUrlAtendSac + 'AtendSacAtendente/ListarAtendSacAtendente', this.dadosLoginSession.fccTokenHeaders)
        .then(response => {
          this.listaAtendentes = response.data
          lista.push(response.data)
          if (this.listaAtendentes.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.listaAtendentes.length; i++) {
              this.listaAtendenteNovas.push(this.listaAtendentes[i])
              var objListaimagem = []
              axios.get(this.$store.state.baseUrlSga + 'File/DownloadIdExt?idExt=' + this.listaAtendentes[i].usuId + '&codArqCad=AFU', this.dadosLoginSession.fccTokenHeaders)
                .then(response => {
                  objListaimagem.push(response.data)
                })
            }
            var novo = [].concat(lista, objListaimagem)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(novo))
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setErrorSystem(error)
        })
    },
```

No this.listaAtendentes ele retorna essa lista:

```
   {
      "idAtendente":2,
      "usuId":"vovozinho",
      "idArquivo":1358,
      "cdFuncionario":0,
      "valid":false,
      "lista":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "idAtendente":3,
      "usuId":"jjoao",
      "idArquivo":1362,
      "cdFuncionario":0,
      "valid":false,
      "lista":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

agora no objListaimagem ele retorna esse objeto:

```
[
   {
      "arqid":1352,
      "repoid":10,
      "arqcadid":22,
      "arqchaverepositorio":"92",
      "arqnomeoriginalarquivo":"atela.PNG",
      "arqextensao":".PNG",
      "arqtamanhokb":"1137426",
      "arqmetadata":null,
      "arqlinkext":"DESENV/",
      "arqpublico":true,
      "arqdatacriacao":"2020-12-22T11:37:21.16",
      "arqdataexclusao":null,
      "arqmimetype":null,
      "arqnomearquivo":"92.PNG",
      "arqidexterno":"vovozinho",
      "arqcadcodigo":"AFU",
      "arqrepoorigem":null,
      "arqrepodestino":null,
      "arqseqrepositorio":92,
      "arqurl":"http://cdn.teste.com.br/DESENV//92.PNG",
      "mensagem":null
   }
]
```

Preciso pegar a penultima propriedade do objeto acima (arqurl) e adicionar no objeto da lista correspondente ao parametro passado, de forma que a primeira lista (this.listaAtendentes) fique assim para cada objeto:

```
{
      "idAtendente":2,
      "usuId":"vovozinho",
      "idArquivo":1358,
      "cdFuncionario":0,
      "valid":false,
      "lista":[],
      "arqurl":"http://teste.com.br/DESENV//92.PNG", <------- item adicionado
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma vez que vc ja tem a lista principal vc pode apenas mutar o objeto no array

```js
      axios.get(this.$store.state.baseUrlAtendSac + 'AtendSacAtendente/ListarAtendSacAtendente', this.dadosLoginSession.fccTokenHeaders)
        .then(response => {
          this.listaAtendentes = response.data
          for (let item of this.listaAtendentes) {
              axios.get(this.$store.state.baseUrlSga + 'File/DownloadIdExt?idExt=' + this.listaAtendentes[i].usuId + '&codArqCad=AFU', this.dadosLoginSession.fccTokenHeaders)
                .then(response => {
                  item.lista.push(response.data)
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setErrorSystem(error)
        })
    },
```